# ObjectMapper to map json to Object

Tags: java, json, datamapper

I have an object Organization.

```
Class Phone{
    String type;
    String number;

    String getType(){
        return type;
    }

    String setType(String t){
        type = t;
    }

    String getNumber(){
        return number;
    }

    String setNumber(String n){
        number = n;
    }
}

Class Organization() {
    String orgName;
    Phone[] phone;

    String getOrgName(){
        return orgName;
    }

    String setOrgName(String name){
        orgName = name;
    }

    String getPhone(){
        return phone;
    }

    String setPhone(Phone[] phone){
        phone = phone;
    }
}
```

I am trying to convert a Json to this Object.

```
{   
"OrgName": "Some Org", 
"phone": [
    { "type": "Phone 1", "number": "555 555-1234" },
    { "type": "Phone 2", "number": "555 555-4567" }
]
}
```

The function I have that works on orgName is as follows:

```
private static Object jsonToObject(String json, Class<?> c) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Object obj = null;
    try {
        obj = objectMapper.readValue(json, clazz);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception " + e);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

I call it: Organization org = (Organization)jsonToObject(json, Organization.class);

exception org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Phone"

Comment: what language are you using? `Class Organization() {` is not Java.
() in class name declaration and `Class` instead of `class`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should you use `public` access modifier in your classes definition. Next, for converting java object to / from JSON object, you should use **java jackson** library. Something like this:

```
String jsonString = "{'OrgName': 'Some Org', 'phone':[{'type': 'Phone1','number': '555 555-1234'}, {'type': 'Phone 2', 'number': '555 555-4567' }]}";
Organization organization =  mapper.readValue(jsonString, Organization.class);
```

Also, jackson has some useful annotations and you can customize it for yourself. It has good resources on the internet for your learning.

For more inforation about jackson, you can use these links:

[How to convert Java object to / from JSON (Jackson)](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)

[Java Jackson tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson/)

Answer (score 0):

**class Organization { // }**

**class Phone { // }**

Looks more like java.